# Commerce Default Product change not working fully

Tags: commerce

```
function default_select_commerce_product_reference_default_delta_alter(&$delta, $products) {
    dsm($products);

  foreach ($products as $key => $product)  {
    if (!isset($currentlowest)) {
    $delta = $key; 
    } elseif ((int)$product->commerce_price[und][0][amount] < $currentlowest) {
         $delta = $key;   
      }
  }
}
```

This is not picking the item with the lowest price, it is working but not picking the lowest price, it seems to be ignoring 2 of the attributes of the products.

Comment: can u please the output of dsm here and value of currentlowest so that anyone would be in a better position to guide you out

Comment: Hi Harshal, is there an easy way to do this, I can't exactly just copy and paste it can I?